# How to disable submit button in React Final Form when FormSpy is used?

Tags: javascript, forms, react-final-form

I am working on a template from sharetribe and I had to modify a *date availability filter*, but I got stuck when I wanted to condition the submit button to disable when nothing is selected from the dates pannel. I tried to add the props *submitting, pristine, invalid* and use them for this, but it didn't work.
Here is the code :

```js
const FilterFormComponent = props => {
  const { liveEdit, onChange, onSubmit, onCancel, onClear, ...rest } = props;

  if (liveEdit && !onChange) {
    throw new Error('FilterForm: if liveEdit is true you need to provide onChange function');
  }

  if (!liveEdit && !(onCancel && onClear && onSubmit)) {
    throw new Error(
      'FilterForm: if liveEdit is false you need to provide onCancel, onClear, and onSubmit functions'
    );
  }

  const handleChange = formState => {
    if (formState.dirty) {
      onChange(formState.values);
    }
  };

  const formCallbacks = liveEdit ? { onSubmit: () => null } : { onSubmit, onCancel, onClear };
  return (
    <FinalForm
      {...rest}
      {...formCallbacks}
      mutators={{ ...arrayMutators }}
      render={formRenderProps => {
        const {
          id,
          form,
          handleSubmit,
          onClear,
          onCancel,
          style,
          paddingClasses,
          intl,
          children,
          submitting
        } = formRenderProps;

        const handleCancel = () => {
          // reset the final form to initialValues
          form.reset();
          onCancel();
        };

        const clear = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'FilterForm.clear' });
        const cancel = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'FilterForm.cancel' });
        const submit = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'FilterForm.submit' });

        const classes = classNames(css.root);

        const spy =
          liveEdit || onChange ? (
            <FormSpy onChange={handleChange} subscription={{ values: true, dirty: true }} />
          ) : null;

          const handleButtonsAvailability = spy ? false : true;

        const buttons = !liveEdit ? (
          <div className={css.buttonsWrapper}>
            <button className={css.clearButton} type="button" onClick={onClear}>
              {clear}
            </button>
            {/* <button className={css.cancelButton} type="button" onClick={handleCancel}>
              {cancel}
            </button> */}
            <button className={css.submitButton} disabled={handleButtonsAvailability} type="submit">
              {submit}           //this is the submit button I want to disable
            </button>
          </div>
        ) : null;

        return (
          <Form
            id={id}
            className={classes}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            tabIndex="0"
            style={{ ...style }}
          >
            <div className={classNames(paddingClasses || css.contentWrapper)}>{children}</div>
            {spy}
            {buttons}
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

FilterFormComponent.defaultProps = {
  liveEdit: false,
  style: null,
  onCancel: null,
  onChange: null,
  onClear: null,
  onSubmit: null,
};

FilterFormComponent.propTypes = {
  liveEdit: bool,
  onCancel: func,
  onChange: func,
  onClear: func,
  onSubmit: func,
  style: object,
  children: node.isRequired,

  // form injectIntl
  intl: intlShape.isRequired,
};

const FilterForm = injectIntl(FilterFormComponent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add field validation to FilterForms component (which is using React Final Form component). Since fields are passed in through props.children, you need to add the **validate** function to correct field (that handles the date picker).

So, Fields have optional [validate](https://codesandbox.io/s/changing-field-level-validators-zc8ei?fontsize=14) property, which works somewhat like this

```
validate={value => (value ? undefined : "Required")}
```

So, the steps to accomplish this are:

1. Add validator function for the correct Field.
2. Extract "[invalid](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormState#invalid)" value from formRenderProps.
3. Disable submit button if the "invalid" prop is true.

The last step needs something like this:

```
<button className={classNames(css.submitButton, {[css.submitButtonInvalid]: invalid })} type="submit" disabled={invalid}>
  {submit}
</button>
```

In the above code, I assumed that there's CSS Modules class: *css.submitButtonInvalid* that changes the color of the button.

Note 1: there are some existing validators in [src/util/validators.js](https://github.com/sharetribe/ftw-daily/blob/e1d50d4f746b26d09038c049e83dfa6f34940341/src/util/validators.js)

Note 2: You can play with the FilterForm.example.js by opening the */styleguide/c/FilterForm/FilterFormExample* page on your local environment.

Comment: Thanks, was really helpful!